# How to make a program that finds id's of xinput devices and sets xinput some settings

Tags: shell, xinput

I have a G700 mouse connected to my computer. The problem with this mouse in Linux (Ubuntu) is that the sensitivity is very high. I also don't like mouse acceleration, so I've made a script that turns this off. The script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script removes mouse acceleration, and lowers pointer speed
# Suitable for gaming mice, I use the Logitech G700.
# More info: http://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/PointerAcceleration/
xinput set-prop 11 'Device Accel Profile' -1
xinput set-prop 11 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 2.5
xinput set-prop 11 'Device Accel Velocity Scaling' 1.0
xinput set-prop 12 'Device Accel Profile' -1
xinput set-prop 12 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 2.5
xinput set-prop 12 'Device Accel Velocity Scaling' 1.0
```

Another problem with the G700 mouse is that it shows up as two different devices in xinput. This is most likely because the mouse has a wireless adapter, and is usually also connected via a usb cable (for charging). This is my output from `xinput --list` (see id 11 and 12):

```
$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                              id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                    id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                         id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4003   id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech G700 Laser Mouse                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech G700 Laser Mouse                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                             id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                   id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                  id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                  id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This isn't usually a problem, since the id's are usually the same. But sometimes the id's of the mouse change, and that's where my question comes in.

What's the simplest way of writing a script/program that finds the id that belongs to the two listings named `Logitech G700 Laser Mouse` in the output from `xinput --list`, and then running the commands in the top script using those two ids?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: That might be true, but this question is more than 4 years old, and has more than 10k views. Any reason for bringing this up now? Are you going to delete the question?

Comment: No, I don't have plans to delete it. Someone else cited it as "here's a similar question".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do something like the following.

```
if [ "$SEARCH" = "" ]; then 
    exit 1
fi

ids=$(xinput --list | awk -v search="$SEARCH" \
    '$0 ~ search {match($0, /id=[0-9]+/);\
                  if (RSTART) \
                    print substr($0, RSTART+3, RLENGTH-3)\
                 }'\
     )

for i in $ids
do
    xinput set-prop $i 'Device Accel Profile' -1
    xinput set-prop $i 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 2.5
    xinput set-prop $i 'Device Accel Velocity Scaling' 1.0
done
```

So with this you first find all the IDs which match the search pattern `$SEARCH` and store them in `$ids`.
Then you loop over the IDs and execute the three `xinput` commands.

You should make sure that `$SEARCH` does not match to much, since this could result in undesired behavior.

Comment: Can I call this directly from `~/.xinputrc`? It seems like that file gets `source`d but I'm not sure.

Comment: @JarettMillard Yes this looks like a good place to put the script above. But maybe you use the approach of @Schoenix or @SergiyKolodyazhnyy  and make the resulting script executable. To then only add `/path/to/new_script NAME_OF_DEVICE OTHER_OPT` to `.xinputrc`.

Answer (score 21):

If the device name is always the same, in this case `Logitech G700 Laser Mouse`, you can search for matching device IDs by running

```
xinput list --id-only 'Logitech G700 Laser Mouse'
```

Comment: This doesn't work for my logitech mouse (`xinput list --id-only pointer:"Logitech G203 Prodigy Gaming Mouse"`). xinput refuses to print the ids, because "There are multiple devices matching". Kind of silly though.

Comment: +1 for Vinson Chuong - I'm with @MauricioMachado here. This works for me. My mouse is listed in "Virtual core pointer" and "Virtual core keyboard", therefore I'm doing what Markus proposed. e.g. `id="$(xinput list --id-only pointer:'SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse')" 
xinput --set-prop $id 'Evdev Wheel Emulation' 1 
xinput --set-prop $id 'Evdev Wheel Emulation Button' 2` which enables scrolling via middle mouse button click. Thanks.

Comment: For some reason adding the tag `pointer:` works, in other words `xinput list --id-only pointer:'the name'` prints the mouse device ID correctly

Answer (score 8):

My 2 cents for a Logitech Gaming Mouse G502

```
#!/bin/sh


for id in `xinput --list|grep 'Logitech Gaming Mouse G502'|perl -ne 'while (m/id=(\d+)/g){print "$1\n";}'`; do
    # echo "setting device ID $id"
    notify-send -t 50000  'Mouse fixed'
    xinput set-prop $id "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 1
    xinput set-prop $id "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 3
done
```

Answer (score 4):

For the fun of it, same answer, but simpler way to parse and get ids:

```
for id in $(xinput list | grep 'Logitech USB Receiver' |  grep pointer | cut -d '=' -f 2 | cut -f 1); do xinput --set-button-map $id 3 2 1; done
```

Took me a while to figure out this can get the ids:

```
xinput | cut -d '=' -f 2 | cut -f 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I did it like the Answer of Raphael Ahrens but used grep and sed instead of awk and The command is now something like my_script part_of_device_name part_of_property_name_(spaces with \space) value:

```
#!/bin/sh

DEVICE=$1
PROP=$2
VAL=$3

DEFAULT="Default"

if [ "$DEVICE" = "" ]; then 
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$PROP" = "" ]; then 
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$VAL" = "" ]; then 
    exit 1
fi

devlist=$(xinput --list | grep "$DEVICE" | sed -n 's/.*id=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p')

for dev in $devlist
do
    props=$(xinput list-props $dev | grep "$PROP" | grep -v $DEFAULT | sed -n 's/.*(\([0-9]\+\)).*/\1/p')

    for prop in $props
    do
        echo $prop
        xinput set-prop $dev $prop $VAL 
    done 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently I am working on a script for a question over at askubuntu.com , which requires something similar, and I thought I'd share the simple python script that does pretty much what this question asks - find device ids and set properties:

#### The Script

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import subprocess
import sys

def run_cmd(cmdlist):
    """ Reusable function for running shell commands"""
    try:
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmdlist)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as pserror:
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        if stdout:
            return stdout.decode().strip()

def list_ids(mouse_name):
    """ Returns list of ids for the same device"""
    while True:
        mouse_ids = []
        for dev_id in run_cmd(['xinput','list','--id-only']).split('\n'):
            if mouse_name in run_cmd(['xinput','list','--name-only',dev_id]):
                mouse_ids.append(dev_id)
        if mouse_ids:
           break
    return mouse_ids

"""dictionary of propery-value pairs"""
props = { 'Device Accel Profile':'-1',
          'Device Accel Constant Deceleration':'2.5',
          'Device Accel Velocity Scaling':'1.0'   }

""" set all property-value pair per each device id
    Uncomment the print function if you wish to know
    which ids have been altered for double-checking
    with xinput list-props"""
for dev_id in list_ids(sys.argv[1]):
    # print(dev_id)
    for prop,value in props.items():
        run_cmd(['xinput','set-prop',dev_id,prop,value])
```

#### Usage

Provide quoted name of the mouse as first command line argument:

```
python set_xinput_props.py 'Logitech G700 Laser Mouse'
```

If everything is OK, script exits silently, with exit status of `0` , or `1` if any `xinput` command failed. You can uncomment `print` statement to show which ids are being configured (to later double check with `xinput` that values are set alright)

#### How it works:

Essentially, `list_ids` function lists all device ids , finds those devices that have the same name as user's mouse name and returns a list of those ids. Next we simply loop over each one of them, and of each one we set all the property-value pairs that are defined in `props` dictionary. Could be done with list of tuples as well, but dictionary is my choice here.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Add Pointer or Keyboard as a prefix to the device name.

LINUX:~$ xinput --set-prop "Logitech MX Master 2S" 157 5 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 1

Warning: There are multiple devices matching 'Logitech MX Master 2S'.
To ensure the correct one is selected, please use the device ID, or prefix the
device name with 'pointer:' or 'keyboard:' as appropriate.

unable to find device pointer

#Solution

LINUX:~$ xinput --set-prop "pointer:Logitech MX Master 2S" 157 5 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 1